# How do I enable multidex for react native?

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm pretty sure its a built in feature but I cant find anything when searching or in the docs. Is there a flag for building with multidex enabled?

On another note:
Any way to see which libraries are messing with your method count? Hitting the 64k limit came as quite a surprise.

Comment: You want to enable multidex for React Native only?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the answer somewhere else. It's no different than enabling it for any regular Android project.

```
android {
    ....
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

As for method count, this site does the trick: http://inloop.github.io/apk-method-count/

Comment: That is not sufficient.  You need to implementation gradle dependency

Answer (score 84):

For RN 0.59+ and using Gradle 3.4.1, none of the answers here had the complete solution. I did the following and it worked:

1. In `android/app/build.gradle`, update the `dependency` block:

   ```
   dependencies {
       // ... your other dependencies

       // Multidex
       implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
   }
   ```

   And also update the `defaultConfig` in the `android` block:

   ```
   defaultConfig {
       // ... your `applicationId`, etc.
       multiDexEnabled true
   }
   ```
2. In `MainApplication.java`, replace

   ```java
   import android.app.Application;
   ```

   at the top with

   ```java
   import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;
   ```

   **OR** if you're on RN 0.60+ or have manually upgraded to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) then use this instead:

   ```java
   import androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication;
   ```
3. Still in `MainApplication.java`, replace

   ```java
   public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
   ```

   with

   ```java
   public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements ReactApplication {
   ```

Comment: For those who still have the issue following this answer, check whether the following line is correct. The import should be `androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication`. Not `android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication`. This is the import statement that worked for me.

Comment: Added a note and alternate instructions about RN 0.60+ / AndroidX. Thanks @buddhiv !

Comment: I tried everything but it still gives me the issue. Does anyone of you can help with this??

Comment: As suggested below these steps are only needed when minSdkVersion is 20 or less. If you can, upping this version to 21 will fix the issue. Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: Thank you, the `RN 0.60+` tips helps a lot!!

Comment: Does `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'` work even when using RN 0.60+ / AndroidX? In this case, maybe we should use `implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'`. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: @Randam Champ! Should be an answer.

Answer (score 5):

android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
    ....
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

If you are using Multidex, your Application should extends MultiDexApplication instead of Application.

MyApplication.java

```
import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication{
     ...
}
```

Comment: So how do we import MultiDexApplication into the MainApplication file?

Comment: @DanielBarde `import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;`

Comment: android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.ReactApplication

Comment: @octohedron try public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements ReactApplication {

Answer (score 3):

Since `Application` must extend `ReactApplication`, I used a similar approach to [the one suggested here](https://github.com/wuxudong/react-native-charts-wrapper/issues/85#issuecomment-375619348) which is documented in point 2 in the Android Developer [reference on multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle) to attach to the base context:

> app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion projectCompileSdkVersion // Or your version

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion projectMinSdkVersion // Or your version
        targetSdkVersion projectTargetSdkVersion // Or your version
        multiDexEnabled true // *
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true // *
    }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/multidex
}
```

> MainApplication.java

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

However, if your minSdkVersion is set to 20 or lower, then you must use the multidex support library as follows:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Answer (score 0):

**Step:1**

Open the `/android/app/build.gradle`

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true <-- ADD THIS LINE
    }
}
```

**Step:2**

In the same file find `dependencies`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1' <-- ADD THIS LINE
    ...
}
```

Note: To know latest version for multidex [Multidex Latest Version](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/multidex/multidex/)

**Step:3**

Open the `MainApplication.java` file under

```
android/app/src/main/java/.../MainApplication.java
```

Add the multidex Import

```
// ... all your other imports here

import androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication; <-- ADD THIS LINE
```

**Our class definition needs `extends MultiDexApplication` like below**

**Beofre (In my case)**

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
```

**After**

```
public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements ReactApplication {
```

Replace `Application` with `MultiDexApplication`

**Spet:4 (Optional)**

clean the project

Reference [How To Enable Multidex in Android](https://rnfirebase.io/enabling-multidex)

Hope this helps ;)