# Transform Classes With Dex For Debug is making Windows crash

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm building a React Native app. Everything was working fine but now when I try to run on Android it gets to the task :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug, it hangs for 30-60 seconds and then Windows shuts down.

I tried to setup multidex as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56875424 but the result is the same.

I'm not getting any error message, the computer just shuts down abruptly and I have to turn it on again.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you clean the [Event Viewer log](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/302542/how-to-diagnose-system-problems-with-event-viewer-in-microsoft-windows), reproduce the issue, then open back the Event Viewer directly after startup, and search for any critical error ? That might help obtaining an error message

Comment: This could be a real issue with your PC, i guess you may need to go to some PC repair shop.

Comment: Couldn't find any critical error at the shutdown timestamp. But just 1 second before, this is the last thing that gets logged:

Host processor features mask: 0x1004040421B9FFF

Host xsave features mask: 0x15

Host cache line flush size: 64 bytes

Thank you both for your help.

Comment: I'm updating android studio and it's intalling Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD processors. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was two problems mixed:

- I was using the new Windows Terminal which is still in beta so I guess the shutdown problem was something to do with it, because I changed to normal good ol' cmd and the shutdown problem disappeared.
- The actual error in the compilation process was actually the setup of multidex. I was not extending the MultiDexApplication class.

Thank you all.