# My react-native application is unable to launch on android after installing a package containing native code

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, native

Sorry if this question will be a bit too general, but I only hope that someone more experienced than me in react-native and Android can help me with this problem that I now encounter very often.

In fact, I haven't been able to correctly install packages containing native code in my react-native project for a while. The last native package that I successfully installed, not without many problems, it was @react-native-community/google-signin (I think, however, that this is not relevant for this problem)

All the other packages I installed afterwards gave me errors after the installation and I was forced to give up all of these. Initially I thought it was a problem of the individual packages (in fact, as soon as I removed them the app would start working again). Of course, I now have the necessary experience to say that it is a problem shared by all packages containing native code.

Initially I also thought it could be a yarn workspace error, and for this reason, for pre-education, I added all the packages that contain native code in the nohoist list:

```
"workspaces": {
    "nohoist": [
      "react-native",
      "react-native/**",
      "@react-native-mapbox-gl",
      "@react-native-mapbox-gl/**",
      "react-native-gesture-handler",
      "react-native-gesture-handler/**",
      "react-native-reanimated",
      "react-native-reanimated/**",
      "@react-navigation",
      "@react-navigation/**",
      "react-native-safe-area-context",
      "react-native-safe-area-context/**",
      "react-native-vector-icons",
      "react-native-vector-icons/**",
      "react-native-pose",
      "react-native-pose/**",
      "@react-native-community",
      "@react-native-community/**",
      "react-native-elements",
      "react-native-elements/**",
      "react-native-snackbar",
      "react-native-snackbar/**"
    ]
  }
```

Today I tried to install two more packages that I needed: react-native-secure-storage and react-native-snackbar; however I was unable to install them. Like the others, after the installation through yarn or npm, the app is no longer able to start. For example for package react-native-snackbar, iget the following error when starting the app:

> Task :app:mergeDexDebug FAILED

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
206 actionable tasks: 191 executed, 15 up-to-date
Note: mydir\packages\mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\google-signin\android\src\main\java\co\apptailor\googlesignin\RNGoogleSigninModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: mydir\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: mydir\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\reanimated\NodesManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: mydir\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\reanimated\NodesManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# fields: 68231 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:444)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:335)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:50)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:65)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:53)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:217)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:212)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:55)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:116)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# fields: 68231 > 65536)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:21)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:7)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile.a(:33)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile$h.a(:5)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.a(:13)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.write(:35)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(:44)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:23)
        ... 36 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
     The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
     Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.    

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 40s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI 
with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: mydir\packages\mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\google-signin\android\src\main\java\co\apptailor\googlesignin\RNGoogleSigninModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: mydir\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: mydir\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\reanimated\NodesManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: mydir\packages\mobile\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\reanimated\NodesManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# fields: 68231 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:444)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:335)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:50)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:65)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)    
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:53)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:217)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:212)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:55)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:116)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# fields: 68231 > 65536)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:21)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:7)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile.a(:33)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile$h.a(:5)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.a(:13)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.write(:35)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(:44)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:23)
        ... 36 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
     The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
     Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.    

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 40s

    at makeError (mydir\packages\mobile\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at mydir\packages\mobile\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (mydir\packages\mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (mydir\packages\mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I don't have enough development experience with android to understand what the problem is, but I think there is a good chance that it is connected to the migration to AndroidX.

In my project the version of react-native that I am using is 0.62.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable multidexsupport in your build.grade file
Check this
[How to enable multidex support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140496/how-do-i-enable-multidex-for-react-native)

Comment: I know it's not exactly in line with the site's rules, but I wanted to thank you warmly for solving this problem that has been haunting me for days. So thank you @Manjot Singh Dhiman