# How to get crash logs for a React Native Android app that crashes immediately on launch

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I am developing and android app using react-native. Everything was normal until today

**STEPS**

1. I added Firebase following the official [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/) => I started getting an error with the dex archive (the 64k limit)
2. I fixed it following these two links (the [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/enabling-multidex) and a [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140496/how-do-i-enable-multidex-for-react-native))
3. Now when I run `npx react-native run-android`, the build is successful but the app crashes immediately.

**Maybe important notes :**

- react-native version `0.61.5`
- I am using the same computer and phone to debug that I used just before adding firebase
- I added firebase crashalytics (always using the [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/usage)) with firebase before trying it
- I am getting this warning before the build success message and I don't know if it may be related :

```
> Task :app:installDebug
07:48:13 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
07:48:14 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'GBT4C18C21006873' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:48:14 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'JSN-L22 - 10' for app:debug
07:48:14 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'GBT4C18C21006873'
07:48:14 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'GBT4C18C21006873'
07:48:14 D/ddms: Reading file permision of /PATH/TO/PROJECT/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk as: rw-r--r--
07:48:15 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
07:48:18 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'GBT4C18C21006873' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:48:18 V/ddms: execute: returning
07:48:18 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
07:48:18 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'GBT4C18C21006873' : EOF hit. Read: -1
07:48:18 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Comment: `adb logcat` and find the error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found and error in crashalytics, if I can fix it I will mark it as resolved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it !

Thanks to @Guy Incognito who commented my question.

The key is to use `adb logcat` on a terminal and executing `npx react-native run-android` in another terminal. You get a lot of logs from your phone but if you track the exact second in which the build occurred you can easily find the error message and fix it !