# React Native app crashing at startup on Android: Didn't find class "com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerImpl"

Tags: android, react-native, crash, classnotfoundexception

I am using React Native v 0.62.2 and I am trying to get my project running on Android as well. Up until now, I had focussed development on iOS and therefore did never run the Android app. Now I wanted to run the android app but the app crashes on startup right after the splash screen was shown with the following stacktrace:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.myapp.MainApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but DevSupportManagerImpl class was not found or could not be created
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6612)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1896)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but DevSupportManagerImpl class was not found or could not be created
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.a.a(:90)
        at com.facebook.react.q.<init>(:238)
        at com.facebook.react.r.b(:281)
        at com.facebook.react.t.a(:87)
        at com.facebook.react.t.h(:39)
        at com.myapp.MainApplication.onCreate(:48)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6607)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:233) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1896) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerImpl
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.a.a(:68)
        at com.facebook.react.q.<init>(:238) 
        at com.facebook.react.r.b(:281) 
        at com.facebook.react.t.a(:87) 
        at com.facebook.react.t.h(:39) 
        at com.myapp.MainApplication.onCreate(:48) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6607) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:233) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1896) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerImpl" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~WocKG3K03wTNVqsJq3z5Xg==/com.myapp-F972FEHz8FF4xF-BTG7qlg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~WocKG3K03wTNVqsJq3z5Xg==/com.myapp-F972FEHz8FF4xF-BTG7qlg==/lib/x86, /data/app/~~WocKG3K03wTNVqsJq3z5Xg==/com.myapp-F972FEHz8FF4xF-BTG7qlg==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib, /product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379) 
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.a.a(:68) 
        at com.facebook.react.q.<init>(:238) 
        at com.facebook.react.r.b(:281) 
        at com.facebook.react.t.a(:87) 
        at com.facebook.react.t.h(:39) 
        at com.myapp.MainApplication.onCreate(:48) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6607) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:233) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1896) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

I searched the web for solutions or at least hints but did unfortunately not find any solution or even any idea of what could be done to fix this issue.

Does anyone have any idea? Also please let me know if you need any further information in order to be able to answer the question.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: anyone with any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For all who are struggling with this issue as well - after a long period of research plus try and error, I got it finally fixed.

It seems that this issue actually is correlated to OK HTTP. The steps that made me get it running were the following:

1. Enable MultiDex but also keep attention on going for the AndroidX solution (as I use the latest version of React Native which already leverages AndroidX) as stated in the following answer:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/56875424/9055450
2. Follow the instructions given in the following comment adding ProGuard files: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9043#issuecomment-298832659